# DynamoDB record size increasing with time

Tags: amazon-web-services, database-design, amazon-dynamodb, schema

I have a `customer` table in DynamoDB with basic attributes like `name`, `dob`, `zipcode`, `email`, etc. I want to add another attribute to it which will keep increasing with time. For example, each time the user clicks on a product (item), I want to add that to the record so that I have the full snapshot of the customer's profile in a single value indexed by the `customerId`. So, my new attribute would be called `viewedItems` and would be a list of `itemId`s viewed (along with the timestamp).

However, given the 4KB size limit for DynamoDB value, it is going to be surpassed with time as I keep adding the clicked products to the customer profile.

How can I best define my objects so as to perform the following?

1. Access the full profile of the customer by `customerId`, including the views.
2. Access time filtered profile of the customer (like all interactions since last N days), in which case the viewed items should be filtered by the given time range.
3. Scan the entire table with a time filter on `viewedItems`.
4. The query needs to be performant as the profile could be pulled at request time.
5. Ability to update individual customer record (via a batch job, for example, that updates each customer's record if need be).

One way to do this would be to create a different table (say `customer_viewed_items`) with hash key `customerId` and a range key `timestamp` with value being the `itemId` that the customer viewed. But this looks like an increasingly complicated schema - not to mention twice the cost involved in accessing the item. If I have to create another attribute based on (say) "bought" items, then I'll need to create another table. So, the solution I have in mind does not seem good to me.

Would really appreciate if you could help suggest a better schema/approach.

Comment: Ordinarily, I would say that this sounds like a job for an RDBMS but presumably you have reasons not to go that route.

Answer (score 2):

As soon as you really don't know how many items will be viewed by user (edge case - user opens all items sequentially, multiple times) - you cannot store this information in single dynamodb record.

The only solution is to normalize your database and create separate table like you've described.

Now, next question - how to minimize retrieval cost in such scheme? Usually you don't need to fetch **all** viewed items, probably you want to display some of them, then you need to fetch only last X.

You can cache such items in main table customer, ie - create field "lastXviewedItems" and updated it, so it contains only limited number of items without breaking size limit, of course for BI analysis - you will have to store them in 2nd table too.

Comment: How do I cache "last X" items without reading the cache, appending to it and writing it back? I won't know all the last X items at batch processing time.

Comment: @Nik you will need to read/modify/write back, yes, this is how cache works